# What's the best way to integrate Rails Restful Auth App Login into Wiki (MediaWiki?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, wiki, mediawiki

I have a ruby on rails app using restful authentication and I'm looking to add a Wiki to my site.  MediaWiki looks like my best option since it's full featured and I can work with the LAMP stack.  However, I'm not sold on MediaWiki if there's another (preferably open source) app that will integrate better.

I would like to know if anyone can suggest a way to integrate the login of my rails app with MediaWiki so users don't have to login twice or at the very least can have the same login credentials in both the rails and wiki app.

I've looked through the MediaWiki extensions but can't really determine which is the best solution.  The current rails app is hosted on CentOS with enterprise ruby and phusion.

Comment: I have also looked into Xwiki (http://www.xwiki.com/xwiki/bin/view/Home/WebHome) which looks like it has a simple Java interface to extend to handle authentication but I would rather not have to setup a Java/tomcat server.

Comment: You may want to share your experience in https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Requests_for_comment/AuthManager so that such a job is made easier in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps not the cleanest solution but MediaWiki provides support for OpenID.  Similialy, you can modify RESTful authentication to support OpenID here.  This is discussed in the [following post](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=14216).

If both of your applications support OpenID then you've achieved your goals.  If this is an internal solution, clearly this is not ideal.